# Difference between environment variable value for "ECHO %foo%" versus "%foo%"

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, environment-variables, windows-console

What is the difference between

```
ECHO %foo%
```

and simply

```
%foo%
```

In my case the first prints `x` and the second prints `y`, where the "correct" value, the one I want to be returned through `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("foo")` is the `ECHO`ed one, `x`.

I can't figure out how to fix `y` to be `x`. When I run

```
SET
```

I see

```
foo=x
```

which is what I expect. Where is `y` coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ECHO %foo%` calls the `ECHO` command which outputs the value of the `foo` environment variable.

`%foo%` calls the command that's named by the `foo` environment variable found in the current directory or on your path.

You're probably seeing `y` since the command `x` outputs that.

Comment: How can I set the variable returned by `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("foo")` to be `x`?

Comment: @SeeSharp `SET "foo=x"`

Comment: @SeeSharp: There's also `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(string, string)` and `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(string, string, EnvironmentVariableTarget)` as well.